# Redirect to the last page requested after login

Tags: c#, .net

I have one application in which I want a previous requested page after login.

Like if my application session has timed-out and at that time i'm trying to open 'Balance.aspx' - it will then redirect me to the login page & after I login it is redirect to default page, up to this point it works fine, but now I want the previous page requested (balance page) directly after login authenticate?

Could someone please assist?

Comment: What are you writing this in? ASP.NET? MVC? MVC does this already with the default site template.

Answer (score 2):

try below

```
string strRedirect = Request["ReturnUrl"];
if (strRedirect == null)
    strRedirect = @"~/Default.aspx";

Response.Redirect(strRedirect);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here at [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx). This will set up a param in the **querystring** **ReturnURL** which will return the caller to the page after **authenticating**.

Look for a section which has a diagram, this will illustrate how it works *'Forms Authentication Control Flow'*

Answer (score 0):

You can save the last Page with:

> Session["LastPage"] = ....

And then you can redirect to the content of the Session.

Answer (score 0):

after authenticating the page write below **code**:

```
string redirecturl = Request["ReturnUrl"];
if (redirecturl == null)
redirecturl = @"~/Default.aspx";
Response.Redirect(redirecturl );
```